# Entity Framework - DateTime in the where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to convert this code from a stored procedure into a "LINQ to Entities" query:

```
select * from myTable
where venue_date + start_time <= @EndDate
and dateadd(minute, duration * 24 * 60, venue_date + start_time) >= @StartDate
```

As you can see there is some manipulation of dates. This sort of thing won't work because functions such as `.AddHours()` are not supported:

```
where b.Venue_Date.Value.AddHours(b.Start_Time.Value.Hour) <= request.EndDate
```

Something like this won't work either. The error says something about not supporting constructors with parameters:

```
where new DateTime(b.Venue_Date.Value.Year, b.Venue_Date.Value.Month,
  b.Venue_Date.Value.Day, b.Start_Time.Value.Hour, b.Start_Time.Value.Minute,
  b.Start_Time.Value.Second) <= request.EndDate
```

It seems that the Entity Framework is VERY restrictive when dealing with dates. I guess I'll have to use a procedure. The next problem is figuring out how to make a procedure that can populate several related object collections.

Comment: So... what's the actual question here?

Comment: Hi Rex M - I just want to know if there is a way to do this using LINQ or do I have to resort to a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Is changing the schema an option? My experience is that when storing separate columns like:

- Date
- Start Time (as a date)
- Stop time (as a date)

...separately, it's a *huge* advantage to store the date redundantly in the `Date` and `StartTime` columns. Not the least because it makes your query (1) easier to write, and (2) the query can now use an index.

I've done this both ways, and I much prefer this method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Craig. Unfortunately I can't alter the hateful schema :(   - Looking at using a stored procedure via the Entity Framework Extensions now...